# How to traverse a multi-level linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing a C program to save data on managers and employees in a company.

The structure is a multi-level linked list.
Each manager can contain inside managers and employees.

Here is the structure

```
typedef struct Node {
    char* name;
    NODE* next;
    NODE* down;
        NODE* parent; 
    int is_manager;
} NODE;
```

In my program I want to traverse the structure so I can find a specific employee, add to them data, remove them etc.

the add/remove functions are easy - but I'm stuck on how to traverse and search in this structure.

Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Don't make this harder than it needs to be. Write your routines for a single-list first. Once you can do all you need to do for a single-list, then the fact that your nest that code within another list simply means to have to pass the right pointer to your add/remove/search functions to handle the `down` list nested within another one.

Comment: A multi-level linked list can be seen as a *tree* structure. And when working with trees recursion simplifies things a lot.

Comment: I have all the function for a single linked list and still stuck...
I thought about recursion like DFS but couldn't make it

Comment: Take a piece of paper and draw the structure.  They say a picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Simple example: `void print_node(NODE *node) { if (node->down) { print_node(node->down); } /* Now treat node as the head of a list, and print using normal iteration */ }`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But this node also have next...? and the ones inside him also have downs... I just clearly didn't get something right

Comment: The layout of your `struct` is a bit odd. You have an outer list with a payload of `char*` and an inner list where your `down` pointer would be the head, but it is not clear what you are doing with `parent` (unless you are saying for every node in your inner list, `parent` points back to the same node in your outer list).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, for every employee the parent node saves the one in charge of him - the outer list

Comment: will a simple inorder traversal will be ok? to treat the next as right node of a tree, the down as left?

Comment: OK, so this is an Org-Chart setup where you are listing out a management hierarchy. It will work with the single `struct`, but be careful in setting the defaults so you are clear when an employee is also a manager with more people under them. (a tree would be messy as there is a one-to-many aspect that would be difficult to capture - doable, but just really messy)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes its exactly as you said.
Do you have an idea how to traverse it other than tree-like?

Comment: Sure, you choose whether you iterate over all `next` pointers on each pass, and then go `down`. Or you traverse and go `down` at each opportunity remembering to climb back up to `parent` when you hit `next == NULL` So in the first case you treat it like a pyramid and go across each row before going down to the next (loosely), and in the later, you just chase `down` each opportunity you can and back up and across. Chasing down will be a bit more difficult as you need a way to capture where you started `down`. It will just take working the logic out. Try one way, then try the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my example:

```
void print_node(NODE *node)
{
    // Tread node as the head of a list, and iterate over that list the "normal" way
    while (node)
    {
        // But also go down the "tree"...
        if (node->down)
        {
            print_node(node->down);
        }

        // Print the name
        printf("%s ", node->name);

        // And go to the next node in the list
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

By following [the advice by jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513880/how-to-traverse-a-multi-level-linked-list/56514004#comment99613941_56513880) it shouldn't have been to hard to figure this out yourself. Draw it all out using pen and paper, and follow along as you "manually" print that tree.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. Now I'll try doing it by hierarchy :)